# Change four div once use setinterval() 30s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show four div once but a loop. If four div first show after the 30s then four div first hide four div next show after 30s four div first show, four div next hide and keep repeating like that. How to do it?

```
<div class="list-div">  
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything that you can show us? We can help you to fix your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement below code..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.each([4, 5, 6,7], function(i, v) {
  $(".list-div div").eq(v).hide();
 });
  setInterval( function(){ 
 $.each([4, 5, 6,7], function(i, v) {
  $(".list-div div").eq(v).toggle();
 });
 $.each([0, 1, 2,3], function(i, v) {
  $(".list-div div").eq(v).toggle();
 });
  }  , 2000 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-div">  
 <div>ContentG1</div>
 <div>ContentG1</div>
 <div>ContentG1</div>
 <div>ContentG1</div>
 <div>ContentG2</div>
 <div>ContentG2</div>
 <div>ContentG2</div>
 <div>ContentG2</div>
</div>
```

I hope using the above script your problem will be resolved.
**If you want to be set 30 seconds then pass 30000.**
here 1second = 1000

Comment: thank you ! If I have sixteen div, how do you do it?(advance)

Comment: @Vu Thanh tung Using the loop you can do the make dynamic array.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to your elements and then use [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) in jquery to hide/show the divs. The example below toggle hide/show your divs each 3s:

```js
$('.div-2').hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('.div-1').toggle();
  $('.div-2').toggle();
}, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-div">  
    <div class="div-1">Content</div>
    <div class="div-1">Content</div>
    <div class="div-1">Content</div>
    <div class="div-1">Content</div>
    <div class="div-2">Content1</div>
    <div class="div-2">Content1</div>
    <div class="div-2">Content1</div>
    <div class="div-2">Content1</div>
</div>
```

Or without adding class with [:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```js
$('.list-div div:gt(3)').hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('.list-div div:lt(4)').toggle();
  $('.list-div div:gt(3)').toggle();
}, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-div">  
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will work:-

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-div">
    <div class='first'>Content</div>
    <div class='first'>Content</div>
    <div class='first'>Content</div>
    <div class='first'>Content</div>
    <div class='second'>Content1</div>
    <div class='second'>Content1</div>
    <div class='second'>Content1</div>
    <div class='second'>Content1</div>
</div>
<script>
var count = 1;
$('.second').hide();
window.setInterval(function() {   //calls click event after a certain time
   changeDiv();
  }, 30000);
function changeDiv(){
  if(count==1){
    $('.second').show();
    $('.first').hide();
    count=2;
  }else{
    $('.second').hide();
    $('.first').show();
    count=1;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [jQuery.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to load a PHP script generating your HTML DIVs, which you can then do in an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).